# How to find span with highest value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has Ids, start points, end points, and values.  How can I find the 5 mile range that has the highest total value for each ID?  See example below

I have several highways and want to find the busiest 5 mile span on each.  I've divided each road into segments with cars per mile

| Road Name | Mile Start | Mile End | Cars per mile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1 | 10 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 50 |
| A | 3 | 8.5 | 20 |
| .. | ... | .... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE Highway (Road varchar(255), MileStart decimal(10,2), MileEnd decimal(10,2), CarsPerMile decimal(10,2));

INSERT INTO Highway VALUES ('A',0,1, 10), ('A',1,3, 50), ('A',3,8.5,20);
```

For each ID, I want to find the 5 mile range that has the most cars per mile. Eg

| Road | Mile Start | Mile End | Avg Cars per mile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 6 | 32 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: And have you tried anything at all? This isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: Although there may be more than one answer per road, at least one valid answer should either start at a `Mile Start` or end at a `Mile End`. So the first step would be to generate all possible combinations of `{Road Name, Mile Start, Mile Start + 5}` and `{Road Name, Mile End - 5, Mile End}`, and then join those combinations back to your original data to calculate the average cars for that segment. Then it is a matter of picking the best result for each road.

Comment: Added SQL code to generate initial table.

Comment: I've done my research on built-in functions, but couldn't find anything that matches my use case.

Comment: Yeah there won't be a built in function, you'll have to construct a query.

Comment: @Jack I'd try pivoting/exploding your table per mile and do a rolling average with a 5 record lead window. The fractional miles will be tricky though.

Comment: @Error_2646 I considered that, but if the start and end points are in the middle of two segments?  Here is a fiddle for an example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab2a0

Comment: @T N What if the answer starts and end in the middle of segments?  For example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab2a0

Comment: @Jack Is .5 the smallest fractional mile you'll see, or can it be 6.375? If it's either whole or .5, I'd still consider the explode but just by .5 miles and have the window be 10. Or if it's much finer precision, if you have allow for a small error tolerance, explode by .1 miles and have the window be 100.

Comment: @Jack - Since a segment has the same number of cars for the entire length, the average number of cars for the middle 5 miles of a segment > 5 miles would be the same as the average for the first 5 miles or the last file miles. If you had a range that started and ended in the middle of two different segments, you could do at least as good (perhaps better) by sliding that range left or right until you hit a boundary point.  For your example, if you picked a candidate range 2..7, you would do better to slide the range left to 1..6 - covering one more 50-car mile, one less 40-car mile.

Comment: ... The optimal 1..5 range for your fiddle would be one of the `{Road Name, Mile Start, Mile Start + 5}` cases. Using this approach limits the number of calculations if there are  long stretches with no onramps or offramps.

Comment: You are right.  Though I am curious if there ever would be a case where the optimal answer would start and end between two segments.  But for now, I'll take your approach.

Comment: @Jack A couple more hints you may find useful: A standard test for overlapping ranges for your join is `start1 < end2 AND start2 < end1`. This deceptively simple check handles all of the various possible overlap cases.  Once you have an overlap, the size of the overlap would be `LEAST(end1, end2) - GREATEST(start1, start2)` in SQL Server 2022, or the equivalent `CASE` or `IIF` expressions in earlier versions. One more thought: You might need to code a special case to handle roads shorter than 5 miles, having either 1 or many segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that the references to "Cars per mile" should actually be "Cars per hour" or similar.

**Assertion:** For any given 5-mile segment of road that has the maximum average traffic, there will be an equivalent 5-mile segment that either starts or ends on one of the input row start/end limits having that same average traffic.

**Argument**: Since a segment has the same number of cars for the entire length, the average number of cars for the middle 5 miles of a segment > 5 miles would be the same as the average for the first 5 miles or the last file miles. If you had a range that started and ended in the middle of two different segments, you could do at least as good (perhaps better) by sliding that range left or right until you hit a boundary point. For your example, if for [this sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab2a0) you picked a candidate range 2..7, you would do better to slide the range left to 1..6 - covering one more 50-car mile and one less 40-car mile.

With that assertion, we can proceed as follows:

1. For each input row, generate two candidate ranges - `{MileStart, MileStart + 5}` and `{MileEnd - 5, MileEnd}`. Eliminate any duplicates.
2. For each candidate, find all overlapping road segments and calculate the combined average traffic. A standard test for overlapping ranges is `start1 < end2 AND start2 < end1`.
3. Rank each result in descending order of combined average.
4. Filter out all but one top result.

The above calculations are performed independently for each road. A road with a total length of less than 5 miles will have a slightly different combined average calculation, but we need to be careful not to consider a short starting or ending segment as an acceptable answer for a longer road.

The result will be something like the following:

```
;WITH CTE_Ranges AS (
    -- Any peak 5-mile stretch is guaranteed to have an equivalent that
    -- either starts or ends on one of the data point limits.
    -- So we only need to sample these ranges.
    SELECT DISTINCT H.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd
    FROM Highway H
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (MileStart, MileStart + 5),
            (MileEnd - 5, MileEnd)
    ) R(RangeStart, RangeEnd)
),
CTE_Averages AS (
    -- For each range, find overlapping road segments, calculate the overlaps,
    -- and aggregate the averages
    -- Note that for a short road < 5 miles, the calculated ActualStart/ActualEnd
    -- will be different from RangeStart/RangeEnd.
    SELECT
        R.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd,
        MIN(C1.OverlapStart) AS ActualStart,
        MAX(C1.OverlapEnd) AS ActualEnd,
        SUM(C2.OverlapLength) AS ActualLength,
        SUM(H.CarsPerMile * C2.OverlapLength) / 5 AS Average,  -- Rank by this
        SUM(H.CarsPerMile * C2.OverlapLength)
            / (MAX(C1.OverlapEnd) - MIN(C1.OverlapStart))
            AS AdjustedAverage                                 -- But display this
    FROM CTE_Ranges R
    JOIN Highway H
        ON H.RoadName = R.RoadName
        AND H.MileStart < R.RangeEnd
        AND H.MileEnd > R.RangeStart
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            -- LEAST() and GREATEST() are defined in SQL Server 2022 or later.
            -- If running an earlier version, substitute equivalent CASE or IIF() logic.
            GREATEST(H.MileStart, R.RangeStart) AS OverlapStart,
            LEAST(H.MileEnd, R.RangeEnd) AS OverlapEnd
    ) C1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT OverlapEnd - OverlapStart  AS OverlapLength
    ) C2
    GROUP BY R.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd
),
CTE_Rank AS (
    -- Assign rankings - highest average first.
    -- Throw in start mile as an stablizing tiebreaker.
    SELECT
        A.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY A.RoadName
            ORDER BY A.Average DESC, A.ActualStart
            ) AS Rank
    FROM CTE_Averages A
)
-- Only the best is selected here.
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Rank R
WHERE R.Rank = 1
ORDER BY R.RoadName
```

The above uses *common table expressions* (CTEs) to build up the data to eventually achieve the final result. If you prefer, all of these CTEs can be incorporated into the final query as nested subqueries. `CROSS APPLY`s are also used as a convenient way to calculate intermediate results in a query to avoid duplicate expressions and reduce complicated calculations in the select lists. If you prefer, these calculations could also be substituted back into the main select list calculations.  I not expect that there would be any performance difference with any of these alternate forms. (My preference is to keep the steps separate.)

The above also uses the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions only available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions, the following substitute calculations can be used:

```
IIF(H.MileStart > R.RangeStart, H.MileStart, R.RangeStart) AS OverlapStart,
IIF(H.MileEnd < R.RangeEnd, H.MileEnd, R.RangeEnd) AS OverlapEnd
```

Results (with some extra data):

| RoadName | Range Start | Range End | Actual Start | Actual End | Actual Length | Average | Adjusted Average | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.00 | 6.00 | 1.00 | 6.00 | 5.00 | 32.0 | 32.00 | 1 |
| B | 1.00 | 6.00 | 1.00 | 6.00 | 5.00 | 40.0 | 40.00 | 1 |
| C | -2.00 | 3.00 | 0.00 | 3.00 | 3.00 | 24.0 | 40.00 | 1 |
| D | 3.50 | 8.50 | 3.50 | 8.50 | 5.00 | 30.0 | 30.00 | 1 |

Some of these results are present just to demonstrate intermediate logic and can be eliminated from the final select and possibly from the earlier steps in the query.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gXERG7WR) for a demo with some extra data.

If the CTE_Ranges to Highway overlap matching join causes performance issues, it may be possible to rewrite the query into two separate parts - one optimized for `{MileStart, MileStart + 5}` range lookups that uses an index `Highway(RoadName, MileStart)` and the other  optimized for `{MileEnd - 5, MileEnd}` range lookups that uses an index `Highway(RoadName, MileEnd)`. The two results could then be merged, and the *best of both worlds* selected.

**Addendum:** I implemented the above so that it uses two separate lookups optimized to use separate indexes for the low-range and high-range cases. When I added a road with 1000 segments to the test data and examined the execution plans, the original query above showed about 500k rows read, while the optimized query showed only about 6k rows read. (For some reason I had to add index hints to force SQL Server to use intended indexes.)

The updated query is as follows:

```
WITH CTE_Ranges AS (
    -- Any peak 5-mile stretch is guaranteed to have an equivalent that
    -- either starts or ends on one of the data point limits.
    -- So we only need to sample these ranges.
    SELECT H.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd, MIN(R.LowOrHigh) AS LowOrHigh
    FROM Highway H
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (1, MileStart, MileStart + 5),
            (2, MileEnd - 5, MileEnd)
    ) R(LowOrHigh, RangeStart, RangeEnd)
    GROUP BY H.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd -- De-dup
),
CTE_Averages AS (
    -- For each range, find overlapping road segments, calculate the overlaps,
    -- and aggregate the averages
    -- Note that for a short road < 5 miles, the calculated ActualStart/ActualEnd
    -- will be different from RangeStart/RangeEnd.
    SELECT
        R.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd,
        MIN(C1.OverlapStart) AS ActualStart,
        MAX(C1.OverlapEnd) AS ActualEnd,
        SUM(C2.OverlapLength) AS ActualLength,
        SUM(H.CarsPerMile * C2.OverlapLength) / 5 AS Average,
        SUM(H.CarsPerMile * C2.OverlapLength)
            / (MAX(C1.OverlapEnd) - MIN(C1.OverlapStart))
            AS AdjustedAverage
    FROM CTE_Ranges R
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- For low-end ranges only, look up segments based on MileStart
        -- Optimized for Highway(RoadName, MileStart) index
        SELECT H1.*
        FROM (SELECT 1 AS Test WHERE R.LowOrHigh = 1) T1 -- Only join for low-end
        CROSS JOIN Highway H1 WITH(INDEX(IX_Highway_RoadName_MileStart))
        WHERE H1.RoadName = R.RoadName
        AND H1.MileStart >= R.RangeStart  -- H1.MileEnd > R.RangeStart is guaranteed
        AND H1.MileStart < R.RangeEnd

        UNION ALL

        -- For high-end ranges oonly, look up segments based on MileEnd
        -- Optimized for Highway(RoadName, MileEnd) index
        SELECT H2.*
        FROM (SELECT 1 AS Test WHERE R.LowOrHigh = 2) T2 -- Only join for high-end
        CROSS JOIN Highway H2 WITH(INDEX(IX_Highway_RoadName_MileEnd))
        WHERE H2.RoadName = R.RoadName
        AND H2.MileEnd > R.RangeStart
        AND H2.MileEnd <= R.RangeEnd  -- H2.MileStart < R.RangeEnd is guaranteed
    ) H
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            -- LEAST() and GREATEST() are defined in SQL Server 2022 or later.
            -- If running an earlier version, substitute equivalent CASE or IIF() logic.
            --GREATEST(H.MileStart, R.RangeStart) AS OverlapStart,
            --LEAST(H.MileEnd, R.RangeEnd) AS OverlapEnd
            IIF(H.MileStart > R.RangeStart, H.MileStart, R.RangeStart) AS OverlapStart,
            IIF(H.MileEnd < R.RangeEnd, H.MileEnd, R.RangeEnd) AS OverlapEnd
    ) C1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT OverlapEnd - OverlapStart  AS OverlapLength
    ) C2
    GROUP BY R.RoadName, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd, R.LowOrHigh
),
CTE_Rank AS (
    -- Assign rankings - highest average first.
    -- Throw in start mile as an stablizing tiebreaker.
    SELECT
        A.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY A.RoadName
            ORDER BY A.Average DESC, A.ActualStart
            ) AS Rank
    FROM CTE_Averages A
)
-- Only the best is selected here.
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Rank R
WHERE R.Rank = 1
ORDER BY R.RoadName
```

The above requires that the following indexes be defined:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Highway_RoadName_MileStart
    ON Highway(RoadName, MileStart)
    INCLUDE(MileEnd, CarsPerMile)
CREATE INDEX IX_Highway_RoadName_MileEnd
    ON Highway(RoadName, MileEnd)
    INCLUDE(MileStart, CarsPerMile)
```

The `INCLUDE(...)` portion makes these *covering indexes* that saves a PK lookup (clustered index seek) back into the main table.

The main change is in the matching segment lookup, which is now a UNION of two subqueries. A *guard* condition is inserted in the FROM clause to selectively allow or block each lookup from proceeding.  Some minor changes were also made to CTE_Ranges to add a low/high indicator and to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT to de-dup.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qOEcJNwW) which includes both the new and original queries, extra test data, and execution plan displays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and support man.  Yeah you are right that the optimal segment will either begin at a segment start point or end at a segment end point.  This assertion cuts down the number of ranges to check and improves performance!  

My use case is massive, so I put some of the intermediate CTEs in temp tables to get it to run.  Same structure though

Comment: @Jack - I have a bonus for you. Since you said your "use case is massive", I went ahead and implemented my optimization idea.  See my addendum above. You should of course performance-test the above and Martin Smith's solution to see which one really works best against the real data. Don't forget the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

A brute force approach would be to simply expand out all segments to `0.01` of a mile (the most granular supported by the datatype) and then use a sliding window of `ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to calculate each 5 mile segment in turn ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZJCQ8g0r)).

I use `generate_series` below to do the expansion. This could be replaced with a join on a numbers table if you are not on a version with that function.

```
WITH exploded AS
(
SELECT value AS MileStart, value + 0.01 AS MileEnd,  CarsPerMile * 0.01 AS Cars, Road
FROM Highway
CROSS APPLY generate_series(MileStart, CAST(MileEnd-0.01 AS decimal(10,2)), CAST(0.01 AS decimal(10,2)))
), withtotals AS
(
SELECT  MIN(MileStart) OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY MileStart ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SegmentStart,
        MileEnd AS SegmentEnd,
        MileEnd - MIN(MileStart) OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY MileStart ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Distance,
        SUM(Cars) OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY MileStart ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CarsInSegment,
        Road
FROM exploded
), ranked AS
(
SELECT *, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY CarsInSegment DESC) AS Rnk
FROM withtotals
where Distance = 5
)
SELECT Road, SegmentStart, SegmentEnd, CarsInSegment/5 AS [Avg Cars per mile]
FROM ranked
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

If you have a covering index on `(Road, MileStart)` then a more convoluted version that avoids any sort operations is...

([Fiddle borrowing @TN's sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/G5B-wpYZ))

```
WITH exploded AS
(
SELECT value AS MileStart, value + 0.01 AS MileEnd,  CarsPerMile * 0.01 AS Cars, Road, MileStart AS RawMileStart
FROM Highway
CROSS APPLY generate_series(MileStart, CAST(MileEnd-0.01 AS decimal(10,2)), CAST(0.01 AS decimal(10,2)))
), withtotals AS
(
SELECT  MIN(MileStart) OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY RawMileStart, MileStart ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SegmentStart,
        MileEnd AS SegmentEnd,
        MileEnd - MIN(MileStart) OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY RawMileStart, MileStart ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Distance,
        SUM(Cars) OVER (PARTITION BY Road ORDER BY RawMileStart, MileStart ROWS BETWEEN 499 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CarsInSegment,
        Road
FROM exploded
), maxes AS
(
SELECT Road, 
       CarsInSegment = CAST(JSON_VALUE(MAX(ConcatValue), '$.CarsInSegment') AS decimal(10,4)),
       SegmentStart =  CAST(JSON_VALUE(MAX(ConcatValue), '$.SegmentStart') AS decimal(10,2)),
       SegmentEnd =    CAST(JSON_VALUE(MAX(ConcatValue), '$.SegmentEnd') AS decimal(10,2))
FROM withtotals
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONCAT('{"CarsInSegment":"',FORMAT(CarsInSegment, '0000000000.0000'),'","SegmentStart":',SegmentStart,',"SegmentEnd":',SegmentEnd,'}'))CA(ConcatValue)
GROUP BY Road
)
SELECT  Road, 
        SegmentStart, 
        SegmentEnd, 
        CarsInSegment/5 AS [Avg Cars per mile]
FROM maxes
WHERE SegmentEnd = SegmentStart +5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reopen. I thought it was premature to close a question where the OP was actively responding to questions in the comments and expanding the question with sample data and expected results. Seems to happen too much on SO. I also though that the problem statement itself was sufficiently well described, boiling down to finding a fixed width interval against data having variable width intervals using some value calculation to select the optimal result.

Comment: Yeah SO can be nasty.  I was using ChatGPT until you came along.

I really appreciate the brute force solution, and take my upvote.  But T N convinced me it’s not needed, so I’m going to accept his answer for now.  

Thank you